# What is the SonarQube Web API to retrieve all projects/resources which are using a specific quality profile?

Tags: api, resources, sonarqube, profiles

What is the SonarQube Web API to retrieve all projects/resources which are using a specific quality profile ? I know we have API to get all profiles used for a project, But my requirement is just in contrast.

Resources: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392180

Profiles: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392177

Can anyone help here?

Thanks and regards,
Narasimha

Answer (score 0):

Use the web service [api/qualityprofiles/projects](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/qualityprofiles/projects) to retrieve projects associated with a specific quality profile.